# why is Color view transparent in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

[image]

i have this card thing in the picture to build, here're the code:

```
struct ArticleCard: View {
    var article: Article

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.white
                .border(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.2))
                .shadow(color: Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.2), radius: 0.0, x: 5, y: 5)
        
            VStack{
                Text(article.title)
                    .padding(.top, 5)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .padding(.trailing)
                    .font(.title2)
              
                Image(article.coverUrl).resizable()
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .padding(.trailing)
            
                Text(article.title)
                    .padding(.leading)
                    .padding(.trailing)
                    .padding(.bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the ZStack i put a Color.white there as a background of the card, and give this color view a shadow, but the color seems to be transparent, therefor i got unwanted lines on the top and the left inside the borders, how do i get rid of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using border and shadow in wrong place, try this:

PS: there is no reason of using **Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.2)** you can use this: **Color.black.opacity(0.2)**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            
            Color.white
            
            VStack {
                
                Text("article.title")
                    .padding()
                
                Image(systemName: "star")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()

                Text("article.title")
                    .padding()
                
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        .border(Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.2))
        .compositingGroup()
        .shadow(color: Color(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, opacity: 0.2), radius: 0.0, x: 5, y: 5)

    }
}
```

[image]

---

I refactored your code for better and less code as possible you can use Image instead of Text in your App.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            
            Text("your custom Text")
                .padding()
            
            Text("")
                .font(Font.system(size: 150))

            Text("your custom Text")
                .padding()
            
        }
        .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        .background(Color.white)
        .border(Color.black.opacity(0.2))
        .compositingGroup()
        .shadow(color: Color.black.opacity(0.2), radius: 0.0, x: 5, y: 5)
        
    }
}
```

[image]